# ¿por qué no funciona un for dentro de otro?

Tags: java, iteraciones

Debo entregar unos programas en consola para mañana, pero uno me está fallando. No sale error, sólo que no hace lo que yo espero.

Necesito que este ciclo repita 18 veces otro ciclo, pero sólo lo hace una vez y ya.

Gracias de antemano por su ayuda.

```
package ejercicios_ciclos;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;
public class inscripcion {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´´");
        System.out.println("SISTEMA DE INSCRIPCIONES");
        System.out.println("------------------------");
        System.out.println("~~~~~~~~CBTis #59~~~~~~~");
        System.out.println("________________________");
        System.out.println("________________________");
        System.out.println("");

        int nau, nal, i, n=1;

        String nombre, esc, prom;

        for(i=1;i<19;i++){
            System.out.println("AULA NUMERO " + i);
            for(nal=n;n<51;n++){
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''");
                nombre = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Nombre:");
                esc = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Escuela de procedencia:");
                prom = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Promedio:");

                System.out.println("PROMEDIO DE SECUNDARIA: " + prom);
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("NOMBRE DEL ALUMNO: " + nombre);
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("ESCUELA ANTERIOR: "+ esc);
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("NÚMERO DE CONTROL = 0" + n);
                System.out.println("______________________________________________");

                System.out.println("PROMEDIO DE SECUNDARIA: " + prom);
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("NOMBRE DEL ALUMNO: " + nombre);
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("ESCUELA ANTERIOR: "+ esc);
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("NÚMERO DE CONTROL = 0" + n);
                System.out.println("______________________________________________");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: En el segundo `for()` no estás actualizando la variable `nal`

Answer (score 6):

Hechos

- `n` esta definido por fuera del primer `for`.
- en el `for` interior no se reestablece el valor de `n` para cada ciclo del `for` mas exterior.

Conclusion:

Luego de completar el primer ciclo, ya no vuelve a entrar al `for` interior pues  `n >= 51`.

Solución: donde dice..

```
for(nal=n;n<51;n++){
```

Cambia por...

```
for(n=1;n<51;n++){
```

El valor de `n` volverá a 1 para cada ciclo exterior y por ende reingresando en el bucle interior.

Sin embargo, una mejor practica sería definir la variable dentro del propio `for`...

```
for(int n=1; n < 51; n++) {
```

(deberías eliminar la definición anterior)

Answer (score 2):

El bucle sí se ejecuta 18 veces, sólo que por un error en el segundo bucle `for(nal=n;n<51;n++)` hace que `n` no se reinicie a 1 por lo que los bucle 2 al 18 pasan directamente escribiendo esto:

```
AULA NUMERO 2
AULA NUMERO 3
AULA NUMERO 4
AULA NUMERO 5
AULA NUMERO 6
AULA NUMERO 7
AULA NUMERO 8
AULA NUMERO 9
AULA NUMERO 10
AULA NUMERO 11
AULA NUMERO 12
AULA NUMERO 13
AULA NUMERO 14
AULA NUMERO 15
AULA NUMERO 16
AULA NUMERO 17
```

Para corregirlo reemplaza el segundo bucle errado por `for(n=1;n<51;n++)` y el problema se solucionará.

Espero te sea de ayuda.

**Off topic:** Te sugiero usar variables más explícitas como numeroAlumnos en lugar de n, al igual que para `nau` y `nal`, lo que hará tu código más legible.

Comment: el OP nunca dice que el ciclo no se ejecuta 18 veces, dice que ciclo interior no se ejecuta 18 veces.

Comment: @rnd cito: "Necesito que este ciclo repita 18 veces", claramente se ve que se está refiriendo al primer bucle de `for(i=1;i<19;i++)`, luego de cada bucle hace la solicitud de datos pero luego del primer bucle deja de pedirlo pues el segundo bucle no se ejecuta por lo ya explicado, todo esto provoca la sensación de que el primer bucle solo funciona una vez como la pregunta menciona.

Comment: Cito "necesito que este ciclo repita 18 veces **otro ciclo**" (énfasis mío).

Comment: Creo que ambos hemos entendido lo mismo pero lo estamos explicando de diferente manera, nuestras soluciones son las mismas en cuanto al cambio de código que debe darse.

Answer (score 1):

Remplaza la siguiente parte de tu código e intentalo de nuevo, el error estaba en tu variable `nal`, puedes probarlo si gustas con un numero menor de prueba, por lo que entendi, ingresas 51 alumnos por cada aula, que son 18 en total:

```
for(i=1;i<19;i++)
        {
            System.out.println("AULA NUMERO " + i);
            for(n=1;n<51;n++){
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''");
            nombre = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Nombre:");
            esc = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Escuela de procedencia:");
            prom = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Promedio:");

            System.out.println("PROMEDIO DE SECUNDARIA: " + prom);  
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("NOMBRE DEL ALUMNO: " + nombre);
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("ESCUELA ANTERIOR: "+ esc);
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("NÚMERO DE CONTROL = 0" + n);
            System.out.println("______________________________________________");
        }
```